# triggering my fetched data with my script that combines data with the same value

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter-3

my target is to combine 2 arrays in 1 array if they have the same level.

> For example i have testing 1 = level 1 and testing 4 = level 1. They'll be joined in 1 array because they have the same level.

The below script I provided is what combines 2 arrays in 1 if they have the same level. How can I achieve the target that I stated above? Thank you, guys. I provided my codes and images below.

[[An Image of what I'm fetching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib3bk.png)]
[[An Image of my target when 2 scripts are joined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8X7Z.png)]

Ajax:

```
  var ajaxResult=[]; // the pushed data will be saved here
    var save_method; 
    var table;
    var base_url = '<?php echo base_url();?>';
     
    $(document).ready(function() {
     
        //datatables
        table = $('#entry_list').DataTable({ 
            dom: 'lBfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'print', 'csv', 'copy', 'excel', 'pdfHtml5'
            ],
           
            "processing": false, 
            "serverSide": true,     
            "order": [], 
            
     
        
            "ajax": {
                "url": "<?php echo site_url('controller/fetch_players')?>",
                 "type": "POST",
                 async:true,
                 dataType: "json", 
                 
             
                 success: function(data){
             
                 ajaxResult.push(data); // I'm pushing my data to my ajaxResult variable
       
        
       console.log(ajaxResult);
                  
               
               
                },
                
            },
     
           
            "columnDefs": [
                { 
                    "targets": [ 0 ], 
                    "orderable": false,
                },
                { 
                    "targets": [ -1 ], 
                    "orderable": false, 
                },
     
            ],
     
        });
});
```

script:

```
//script for combiningng data in 1 array if they have the same level. 
    

const ajaxResult= [] // I'm calling here what I fetched on my ajax.
        
        const matching = (list, keyGetter) => {
            let mapping = {};
            const map = new Map();
            list.forEach((item) => {
                const key = keyGetter(item);
                const collection = map.get(key);
                if (!collection) {
        
                    map.set(key, [item]);
                } else {
        
                    collection.push(item);
                }
            });
        
            Array.from(map).map(([key, value]) => Object.assign(mapping, { [key]: value }));
            return mapping
        }
        
        const result = matching(ajaxResult, ({ level}) => { return level});
        
        console.log("RESULT", result);  // when i do console.log, the result me be testing 1 and testing 4 in 1 array, so is testing 2 and testing 4
```

Comment: was there a question here b/c I missed it

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying. My question is how can I achieve my target? my target is to combine 2 arrays in 1 array if they have the same level. I provided more info above. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array.reduce` to achieve the desired behaviour.

```js
const source = [
    {id: 1, name: 'player1', level: 1},
    {id: 2, name: 'player2', level: 2},
    {id: 3, name: 'player3', level: 3},
    {id: 4, name: 'player4', level: 1},
    {id: 5, name: 'player5', level: 2},
    {id: 6, name: 'player6', level: 3},
]

const combine = (source) => {
    return source.reduce((acc,curr) => {
        if(acc[curr.level]) 
            acc[curr.level].push(curr);
        else
            acc[curr.level] = [curr];   
        return acc;
    },{})
}

console.log('Result', combine(source));
```

Explanation:

A reducer iterates through and array and for each iteration, it can hold the result of the previous computation. Using this idea, we first check if we have an array for the level computed, if yes, we just push the current object into the array. If not, we create a new array with the current object as the first element.

P.S: I'd recommend adding logs to check values of `acc` and `curr` on each iteration to understand this better.

Edit: Showcasing how to use with Ajax response:

```js
let ajaxResult = []; // the pushed data will be saved here
let save_method;
let table;
let base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
let result = [];

const combine = (source) => {
  return source.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (acc[curr.level])
      acc[curr.level].push(curr);
    else
      acc[curr.level] = [curr];
    return acc;
  }, {})
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  //datatables
  table = $("#entry_list").DataTable({
    dom: "lBfrtip",
    buttons: ["print", "csv", "copy", "excel", "pdfHtml5"],

    processing: false,
    serverSide: true,
    order: [],

    ajax: {
      url: "<?php echo site_url('controller/fetch_players')?>",
      type: "POST",
      async: true,
      dataType: "json",

      success: function(data) {
        ajaxResult.push(data); // I'm pushing my data to my ajaxResult variable
        result = combine(ajaxResult); // Cleanup your data here. 
      },
    },

    columnDefs: [{
        targets: [0],
        orderable: false,
      },
      {
        targets: [-1],
        orderable: false,
      },
    ],
  });
});
```

Comment: This is much better than the script I did. Is it okay for me to do a follow up question? if yes,

I am fetching data using ajax. how can i pass my fetched data to    " const source "  <<<

So that it'll be dynamic not a static one. Thank you.

Comment: `source` is just an example I provided here assuming that we have the result of the ajax call handy. You can pass the result of your ajax call directly into the `combine()` method as arguments. i.e `combine(ajaxResult)`

Comment: When i'm doing const ajaxresult = [] 

This is what happens. :( It is empty. I did the line 188 console log. 

https://prnt.sc/15wgtcm

Comment: I've added an edit to the answer to include the ajax script. (Click on `Show code snippet` to expand the snippet)

Comment: I applied it and the result is this:: https://prnt.sc/15wprzv 

It is not combining the arrays with the same value, did I miss anything? Thank you for educating me.

Comment: Is it possible to log the `data` and `ajaxResult` before calling `combine()`. Just want to look at the response data structure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233952/discussion-between-psygik-and-rain-ie).